# How do I print an image that is in the clipboard using C#?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, printing, clipboard

I am copying an image to the clipboard like this:

```
using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
{
    chart1.SaveImage(ms, ChartImageFormat.Bmp);
    Bitmap bm = new Bitmap(ms);
    Clipboard.SetImage(bm);
}
```

How do I print the image?

Comment: Erm, pasting it in MSPaint and printing it?  What's the point of putting it on the clipboard?

Comment: "erm" is like "um".  I second hans' question: why are you putting it on the clipboard?

Comment: I think what Hans is trying to say is: When the image is in the clipboard, you need to 'paste' it somewhere (e.g. MSPaint) and print it from there...

Comment: @john well how else would i print it? that is the point. i dont need to use the clipboard but i do need to print the control

Comment: @i am a girl - just print it? The bitmap doesn't need to be in the clipboard to be printed.

Comment: Raymond Chen once put it nicely: "For technical problems, you often get a question that makes you shake your head in disbelief, but upon closer questioning, you find that the person really doesn't want what they're asking for. What they really want is something else, but they've already "solved" half of the problem and only need your help with the other half—the half that doesn't make any sense."

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Pass your Bitmap to this method:

```
void PrintBitmap(Bitmap bm)
{
    PrintDocument doc = new PrintDocument();
    doc.PrintPage += (s, ev) => {
        ev.Graphics.DrawImage(bm, Point.Empty); // adjust this to put the image elsewhere
        ev.HasMorePages = false;
    };
    doc.Print();
}
```

Comment: Error 3 The name 'ev' does not exist in the current context

Answer (score 1):

Use `Clipboard.GetImage()` function to get the image from clipboard, then print as usually. :)

Comment: the question is how do i print it programmtically

Comment: @i am a girl - well then, why the clipboard? It's the `Image` (and `Bitmap` is derived from `Image`) that you need. See plinth's answer.